# Cannot disable AD user due to internal error

Tags: active-directory

cleaning permissions and getting this error on one specific AD user.. 
(other users were disable  with no issues..)
any reason why?

windows Cannot disable object [user name] because: an internal error occurred

Comment: I encountered this behavior. Try refreshing the view, or restart the "users and computers" applet. It usually helps.

Comment: This can be caused by any number of things. You didn't describe very well what exactly you're doing, but the suggestion by @PawełPiwowar to turn it off and on again is a good idea.

Comment: all i did is: 
standing on the user name in the active directory - left mouse key - disable
worked for all other users but on one specific it doesn't... @GabrielLuci i also refreshed and restarted